# Creating a single instance of a class within a Vue application

Tags: vue.js, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm new to Vue and I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to implement what seems to me like a good case for a global variable or singleton.

The background is that I'm using Azure AD B2C for authentication with the MSAL library. MSAL requires a single instance of the `Msal.UserAgentApplication` to be declared and then shared through the application.

What I'm struggling with is how to declare that instance somewhere central and then access it from each component including the router.

At the moment I've got a class which is similar to this example: https://github.com/sunilbandla/vue-msal-sample/blob/master/src/services/auth.service.js and when I want to use the methods I'm doing:

```
var authService = new AuthService();
authService.Login();
```

Unfortunately this creates a new instance of MSAL each time the class is instantiated which in turn caused my users to end up stuck in an authentication loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

---

Following on from the answer below by Teddy I've amended my `main.js` as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import AuthService from './services/AuthService';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$authService = new AuthService();

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And my register.vue component as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is the register page, it should redirect off to B2C</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import router from '@/router.js'

  export default {

    created(){

      this.$authService.isAuthenticated().then(
      function(result){
        if(result){
          router.push('/');  
        }
        else{
          authService.register();  
        }
      });
    }  
  } 
</script>
```

The component is saying that `this.$authService` is undefined so it's obviously not reading the prototype.

It feels like I'm missing something really fundamental in Vue at this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just add it as a Vue instance property. It will be there for all Vue components.

Set it up in main.js like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$authService = new AuthService();
```

You can later access it in any Vue component. For example:

```
this.$authService.Login();
```

Refer:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

Edit:
You have to use this.$router.push and this.$authService.register inside the isAuthenticated callback. If "this" refers to something else in that block, store var self=this; before the callback starts, or use fat arrow syntax.

```
<script>
  //No import as router is available in 'this'
  export default {

    created(){
      var self=this; //For use inside the callback
      this.$authService.isAuthenticated().then(
      function(result){
        if(result){
          self.$router.push('/');  
        }
        else{
          self.$authService.register();  
        }
      });
    }  
  } 
</script>
```

Edit 2:

Maybe you can create the instance (singleton) itself in a file called AuthServiceInst.js. Then you can import it in both main.js and router.js.

New file AuthServiceInst.js:

```
import AuthService from './AuthService.js'

export const authService = new AuthService();
```

main.js:

```
import {authService} from './AuthServiceInst.js'

Vue.prototype.$authService = authService;
```

router.js:

```
import {authService} from './AuthServiceInst.js'

//Now you can use authService
```

Comment: Hi Teddy, thanks for the answer but unfortunately it's not working. I've added a code snipped above in my question if that helps at all? It feels like I've done something really wrong in the setup of Vue.

Comment: You have to use this.$router.push and this.$authService.register inside the isAuthenticated callback. If "this" refers to something else in that block, store var self=this; before the callback starts.

Comment: Thanks Teddy, that works great in the component but I can't access it inside the router. I'll update as soon as I can with a code sample.

Comment: Hi Teddy, turns out the issues with your initial suggestion were all to do with MSAL rather than the Vue side so all good, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndyM Glad I could help

Answer (score 6):

In Vue 3, to declare global instances you need to use `app.config.globalProperties`. This is a replacement of Vue 2's `Vue.prototype` which is no longer present in Vue 3. As with anything global, this should be used sparingly.

```
// main.js
const app = createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .use(vuetify)

app.config.globalProperties.msg = 'hello world'

app.mount('#app')
```

This makes `msg` available inside any component template in the application, and also on this of any component instance:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.msg) // 'hello world'
  }
}
```

Source: [Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue framework or any other frontend framework defining a auth service or any other instance that is a singleton can be defined using a simple variable in your root file.

for example:

```
export const authService = new AuthService(); 
const app = createApp(App) 
app.mount('#app')
```

now since it's in the root file, it gets initialized when the app loads, and it's accessible in our entire app by just importing the authService.

but this instance "must not" be used for storing the user state for example here we can't set the user authentication state ( is it logged in or not ) in the class instance. that's simply because your vue app does not see it as a reactive state. meaning when the isAuthenticated changes to false your application will not rerender or redirect the user to another page.

so you need to handle that using the global state manager for example Pinia or the dependency injection using provide() and inject() methods.
for example in this case exactly after where you call authService.Login() you need the set the isAuthenticated in your global state so the entire app will notice that ( with getters functions ).

Hopefully, my explanations clear out some misconceptions here.